# The only integrable monotone function is zero everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Can someone give me a sketch for proving this:

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a monotone and therefore measurable function. Show that $f$ is integrable if and only if $f(x)=0$.

Some hints would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)>0$ for some $x \rightarrow \int f^+=\infty \rightarrow f $ not integrable.  (in the implications, I used the monotonicity: If $f$ is nondecreasing and $f(a)>0$ for some $a$, then $\int f^+ \geq \int f(a)\chi_{[a,\infty)}=\infty$. )
Similarly, $f(x)<0$ for some $x\rightarrow \int f^-=\infty \rightarrow f $ not integrable.

Comment: But $\int f^-=\infty$ for $f(x)<0$ right? $f^-$ is positive as far as I know?

Comment: @Spark Reading the question, it seems clear its author is *not* able to complete the indications in your answer.

Comment: @P.Sigma I've edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Umm sorry, just another question:

 $\int f(a)\chi_{[a,\infty)}=\infty$ <- Why? And couldn't I just write $\int f\chi_{[a,\infty)}$ instead of $\int f(a)\chi_{[a,\infty)}$?

Comment: @P.Sigma $\int f(a) \chi_{[a, \infty)}=f(a)\int \chi_{[a, \infty)}=\infty$ because the interval [a, \infty) has infinite length.

Answer (score 0):

Just think what does it mean for a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ to be, say, non-decreasing. What would happen if there is some point at which $f$ doas not vanish?

Comment: Then either $f^+ = \infty$ or $f^-=\infty$ which can't be the case if f is integrable, if that is what you mean?